# Eclipse Neon / Maven / error Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 / invalid LOC header

Tags: maven, eclipse-neon

I'm trying to run Maven install command on Eclipse Neon, but all the time the following error appears:

---

[ERROR] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 (C:\Users\Anna.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-install-plugin\2.4\maven-install-plugin-2.4.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

### [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginDescriptorParsingException

I tried to delete the whole folder as suggested in this post [Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3.. error in opening zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631949/failed-to-parse-plugin-descriptor-for-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources-p),  but it didn't resolve my problem.

Any ideas how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to this location

```
C:\Users\Anna.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-install-plugin\2.4\
```

and remove this file

> maven-install-plugin-2.4.jar

or rename it and then do a maven clean from run configuration